# jQuery Mobile app showing monitor dimensions instead of phone screen dimensions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-mobile

I'm adapting my blogging app for mobile by following [Railscast#199](http://railscasts.com/episodes/199-mobile-devices) but with [JQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/) instead of jQTouch.

On my monitor, my application looks fine, but is wide to account for the proportionally wider dimensions of a laptop screen as compared to a phone. It looks perfect if I adjust my browser window to about a third of the width of my laptop screen, which is the view I expected to get on my phone (iPhone 4S). However, when I view the page on my phone, I get the same non-narrowed proportions as on my laptop screen. To clarify, this means that the header is very thin, and all of the buttons and font are tiny.

I could of course just make everything bigger, but based on the resources I've seen, this doesn't seem like the correct approach. After all, it doesn't make sense for the header to render correctly on a monitor but incorrectly on a phone.

What is causing this issue? It seems like maybe somehow I've "forced" a fixed width on the page, but I'm not sure how that could be, as I literally don't have any css outside of jQuery Mobile. Any input/hints would be much appreciated.

**application.mobile.erb**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "mobile" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "mobile" %>
<body>
  <div data-role="page">
    <%= render "layouts/header" %>
    <div>
      <% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
        <div class="alert alert-<%= name == :notice ? "success" : "error" %>">
          <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>
          <%= msg %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
    <div>
      <%= yield %>
      <%= link_to "Full Site", :mobile => 0 %>
      <%= render "layouts/footer" %>   
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**assets/javascripts/mobile.css.scss**

```
/*
 *= require_self
 *= require jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css
 */
```

**assets/javascripts/mobile.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js
```

**view/layouts/_header.mobile.erb**

```
<div data-role="header">
  <h1>Home</h1>
  <% if user_signed_in? %>
    <%= link_to "logout", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %>
  <% else %>
    <%= link_to "login", new_user_registration_path %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Please let me know if there may be other relevant files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `viewport` meta to `head` section of application.mobile.erb

```
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "mobile" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "mobile" %>
```

Comment: Sweet! I knew it was something easy! Thansk @dimuch.